# Open menu on WPF Titlebar click

Tags: wpf, event-handling, click, titlebar

I want to open some custom Menu when the user left-clicks on the titlebar and / or the small icon of my WPF Application.  The Menu itself *must not* open within the titlebar or overlay the titlebar! It's only a nice-to-have feature, but not a must. It can open within the Application itself.

I know that this is "easily" possible with creating a custom window in WPF, but i don't want to do this to maintain all the default window behaviour for now and for future windows versions, as my application lifetime is assumed to be several years.

So my question is:

Can i register some Eventhandlers to the MainWindow's Titlebar without changing the default Window style, behaviour and appearance?

Is it possible to mark the captured Events as "used" or "handled"?